# Exception while connecting to HSM using SunPKCS11

Tags: java, maven, jetty, pkcs#11, hsm

I'm using SunPKCS11 to connect to a HSM device. I have some unit tests which run perfectly(actually they do some signing and verification), however, when I deploy the application into tomcat or jetty I get this exception(this exception is thrown during deployment in jetty, tomcat's exception is alike):

```
java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:103)
        at X.X.X.HsmUtil.<init>(HsmUtil.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBean
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableB
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFac
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:23
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContex
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:952)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:917)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp(JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:477)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_FUNCTION_FAILED
        at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Initialize(Native Method)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11$SynchronizedPKCS11.C_Initialize(PKCS11.java:1545)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.getInstance(PKCS11.java:157)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:330)
        ... 74 more
```

and this is  how I instantiate SunPKCS11:

```
File f = new File(Pkcs11ConfigUtil.getDRIVERCFGPATH());
Provider provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(f.getPath()); //exception is thrown in this line
Security.addProvider(provider);
```

just to add a few details, I'm using a 64bit java8 on a windows server 2012.

update 1:
I just noticed that when I run the tests by maven similar exception occurs, previously I used to run tests using eclipse,
well, I'm not sure what's exactly happening :(

update 2:
I came up with the idea to write a very short piece of code (just a simple and clean class with a main method) to use `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11`, but I faced same problems (while code runs perfectly using eclipse, I get mentioned exceptions when I run the class using java command in `cmd`). It's quite confusing :|

update 3: This is the content of the configuration file

```
name=testname
library=C:\X\Y\Z\cs2_pkcs11.dll
slotListIndex=6
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the configuration file (Pkcs11ConfigUtil.getDRIVERCFGPATH()).

Comment: @always_a_rookie_to_learn check the update

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access classes within package space `sun.*` from within a webapp inside a Servlet container is unsupported by the Servlet spec.

If you read the Servlet spec (SRV.9.7.2) the only package namespace exposed from the JVM and Server container to your webapps are `java.*`, `javax.*`, `org.xml.*`, and `org.w3c.*`.

You'll have to use the `sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11` from outside of a webapp (perhaps as a server component) in order to have any success.

Or, if using something like `embedded-jetty` (and not a formal webapp, or jetty-home, or jetty-standalone, or jetty-maven-plugin) you can sidestep these servlet behaviors / requirements.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Joakim, Do you have any idea about my second update?